# Greenfoot Application - Movement

Tags: java, greenfoot

Hello guys I am new to GreenFoot Java, however with ActionScript 3 I'm okay.

Now I hear that AS3 and Java are very similar.

In Green Foot application can I use

```
public void act() 
{
    if (e.keycode == 39)
       {this.x +=4};
}
```

Or does this only apply for ActionScript 3? 
Sorry if the experts find this question stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, this won't work. I presume there you're trying to find the keycode of an event, and while a similar model exists in native Java, Greenfoot uses a simpler mechanism.

I also assume by adding 4 to `this.x` you aim to move the component horizontally? Again similar concepts exist, but not in that syntax exactly.

In terms of replicating the above, it would be:

```
if(Greenfoot.getKey().equals("t")) { //Obviously replace t with whatever key you want
    setLocation(getX()+4, getY());
}
```

You should read the [Greenfoot API documentation](http://www.greenfoot.org/files/javadoc/) which shows you what methods you have available - if you simply try and crowbar Actionscript syntax into any Java application then fight the compiler until it works, you'll come more than a bit unstuck! While Actionscript and Java aren't too far apart, they're certainly not so similar you can work in that way.

Comment: Hey Berry120, thank you for the answer. I've made a green foot application but I need some help with something.

Do you know any  tutorials on kicking a ball.

//If baby is touching ball (from this point (0.-10)&& e.keycode 32 (space bar) is pressed
{
  //this.y += 5;

}



Here's my pseodu code.

Comment: @Moynzy Not for kicking a ball specifically, but the key topic you'll need for that is collision checking. Have a look at this tutorial (http://www.greenfoot.org/doc/tut-3) which covers that - the other tutorials would be worth working through also, if you haven't already.

Comment: Thank you very much Berry, great help.